# Как вывести значения?

Tags: modx

есть форма

```
[[!FormIt?
               &hooks=`email, redirect,FormItSaveForm`
               &emailTpl=`zayavkaEmailTpl1`
               &emailTo=`extrememod@mail.ru`
               &emailFrom=`postmaster@na-goru.ru`
               &emailSubject=`Новая заявка на [[pdoField? &id=`[[*parent]]` &field=`pagetitle`]] на сайте na-goru!`
               &redirectTo=`134`
               &validate=`rule:required`
               &formName=`Заявка `
               &formFields=`field`
               &fieldNames=`date_start==Дата начала,date_end==Дата окончания,about==Доп текст`
            ]]

     

<form name="contactForm" id="contact-form" class="contact-form form form-equival" method="post" action="">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <label>Ваше ФИО (полностью)</label>
                <input class="input" required type="text" name='fields[0][name]'>
            </div>
           
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <label>Ваш E-mail</label>
                <input class="input" required type="email" name='fields[0][email]'>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid" >
                <label>Ваш телефон (в международном формате)</label>
                <input class="input" required type="text" name="fields[0][phone]">
            </div>
        </form>
```

чанк emailTpl

```
{foreach $fields as $field index=$i}
{$field[phone]}
{$field[email]}
{/foreach}
```

на почту ничего не приходит, вернее этих полей нет

Comment: Тут два вопроса, почему в чанке используете Fenom(а Formit при этом вызываете базовым способом), и почему именование полей нумерованное? Если же рассмотреть более простой случай, то при использовании поля email с именем `email` в форме в вашем чанке emailTpl оно будет доступно через плейсхолдер `[[+email]]` тоже самое для `phone`

Comment: у меня массив полей с возможностью добавить еще